# Is there a function called when a monobehaviour is added? (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a custom component which ive designed as essentially a debugger (a component with lots of custom designed labels that update to display certain "hidden" variables), I want this to work so that you can drag the debugger component onto an object with my other custom controller. I want the same kind of functionality as RequireComponent(). but I don't want it to add the component when I drag it onto any object.

Let me give an example to make it more understandable:
an empty object without my controller should not allow the script to be added and should display an error with Debug.LogError(). (using require component adds the controller)
an object with my controller should allow the debug script to be added with no issues.

If you're wondering how this ties into the title, its because I thought the easiest method would be to have some kind of function called when a script is added/removed. Similar to void Start(), where if the component is added, if no controller script is found, it removes the component and displays an error and vice versa.

Comment: Does the Awake method not work?

Comment: doesnt that run when play is pressed?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You are confusing start and awake. Awake is called when a component is first added or the first time it is enabled. This happens before the game starts, which I assume is what you are confused about.

Comment: Yeah, I tried awake and it didn't quite work the way I wanted so I just gave up, thankyou for the information though.